# Lift framework. Using in enterprise projects

Tags: scala, lift

Does somebody have any experience using Lift framework in enterprise high-load projects?
If so, what problems you got?

Thanks!

p.s. I have already read about experience of Novell company,:-) For me it's not enough.

Comment: Guys (who making downvotes), this is very cool that you can use google search :-). But I ask the stackoverflow community and for YOUR personal experience. Now I see that you don't have and this is also an answer for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also guardian.co.uk; this article talks mostly about scala: http://www.infoq.com/articles/guardian_scala , but at this talk at Skills Matter appearently (I've not found the time to watch it myself yet) Graham Tackley talks about Lift at Guardian: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/lift-guardian

Answer (score 5):

What about [Foursquare](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/ipnci/iamthe_servier_engineering_lead_at_foursquare_ask/)?

Comment: Cool, it's good! I've never seen it before.